# Excel - how to check if certain value appears twice in one column and compare it with another condition

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a problem filtering some data in excel 2007

I would like to check if 2 values appear in one column and compare it with another condition

example

```
Column A, Column B
5555, Yes
5555, Yes
1111, Yes
2222, Yes
1111, No
2222, Yes
3333, Yes
8546, No
2223, Yes
2525, Yes
2223, No
```

I would like to know if 5555 is mentioned twice in column A, and check if the condition is Yes

Tnx in advance

Comment: do you have specific values to check or do you want to look for all duplicates? "check if the condition is Yes" - which one, just one of them or both? Also your desired output isn't clear, please specify what should it be.

Comment: HI Máté, tnx for the fast replay... i want to check if a certain number is mentioned twice or more times in one column and check if the number which is mentioned twice or more times meets the criteria Yes which is in another column... the desired output should be number

Comment: overall, i want to check for all duplicates in one column that meet the given criteria "Yes" and that should give me the number of such cases

Comment: You've accepted an answer, so glad you found a solution.  However, Please clarify something so that this thread is useful for others.  1111 appears twice in col A.  One has Yes in col B, the other has No.  How would that be interpreted?  Is the qualifying count the count of only repeats having Yes in col B, or repeats as long as any occurrence has a Yes?  Suppose there was a 3rd 1111 and it had Yes in col B.  Would two with Yes qualify it even with another having No?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do this using COUNTIF.

Let's say my range for column A is A2 to A6, in cell C2 I would have:

'=IF(AND(IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A$6,A2)>1,TRUE,FALSE),B2="yes"),1,0)'

Then you can paste this down column B, so in cell C3 I would have:

'=IF(AND(IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A$6,A2)>1,TRUE,FALSE),B3="yes"),1,0)'

..etc.

COUNTIF counts the cells in a range which fulfil some criteria, so to break it down:

- `IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A$6,A2)>1,TRUE,FALSE)` is counting values in the range A$2:A$6 which are equal to A2, then if multiples are found (>1) it outputs a true, otherwise it is false.
- `B3="yes"` checks if the value in the B column is "yes".
- The `if(AND([part1], [part2]))` wraps both of those together in a big statement.
- The `1,0` at the end is so that `1` is your output if the whole statement is true, 0 is output if false. Change these values to what you want.

There's a guide to the use of CountIf [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34).

Comment: @MátéJuhász I reread and have now corrected.

Comment: worked like charm!! thanks for the fast response folks! regards