# Unique Data Validation on the result of a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a column that has a 2-word string that I want to be unique, but I want both of those strings to be unique. I can't perform data validation on that column, because if I have a project named "Hello World" and another one named "Hello Darling", data validation will consider it correct, but I want it to point out that it's wrong because I have two project names with the word "Hello". (The project names are always "Adjective Noun", so I don't need to check if position 1 word has been used in position 2)

So my idea was to split the project name into two columns (this I have achieved with `=LEFT(A2, SEARCH(" ",A2,1)-1)` and `=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2) - SEARCH(" ", A2) + 1)` functions.

Good, now I have 2 columns, but now when I have the data validation on the split words data validation does not activate, I'm guessing because it is being executed on the formula (`=LEFT...`, but not the result of the formula itself (`Hello`).

How can I do it so that data validation is performed in a way that both words are being validated?

Answer (score 0):

If this is an option, you could add a helper column and use the output of the helper column as a logic switch for other functions, like data validation or conditional formatting.

Take this as an example:

[image]

Where the formula in the helper column looks like this:

```vbs
=IF(AND(IF(COUNTIF(B$2:B$4,B2)>1,TRUE,FALSE),B2=B2),"Duplicate","Unique")
```

This solution does not consider the presence of apostrophes or the like, which you may want to consider in your final implementation.

I feel like this is only a partial solution for your needs, but cannot infer more with the limited context you've provided.

See the answer on this post for more information:
[Excel - how to check if certain value appears twice in one column and compare it with another condition](https://superuser.com/questions/1038015/excel-how-to-check-if-certain-value-appears-twice-in-one-column-and-compare-it)